# The Search for Climate Forums

Tags: climate, climate-models, world-building

For my fictitious alternate Earth, one of the most important things to consider is that any change in geography and geology can result in profound changes in environment and climate. I've been searching Google for any climate forums that don't focus on our current climate change crisis.

Do you know any climate-based forums on-line that don't focus on our current climate change crisis and allow hard science on fictional climatic patterns?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for recommendations of other locations on the web that discuss fictional scenarios. It's also sat here for some weeks with no answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you know any climate-based forums on-line that don't focus on our current climate change crisis and allow hard science on fictional climatic patterns?

I wish there was one like that, but if you want quality information you need to reach knowledgeable people, and most of them don't have the time to sit around on these forums. They're too busy doing research.

For specifics, your best bet is the scientific literature, which is vast, but a little Google Scholar goes a long way. You'd be surprised how many PDFs are lying around, away from the journal paywall.  If you have more specific queries (e.g. what is the impact of the closing of the Panama Isthmus on North Pacific overturning circulation?) that would help narrow down the search.

For a nice, undergraduate level textbook that does a nice job of presenting big picture climate changes over geologic time, I recommend "Earth's Climate: Past and Future" by William F Ruddiman.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to also consider searching for climate-related articles through known Open Access Journals (e.g. PLoS One). Springer and Elsevier also host some open articles in the field. Having done some teaching on climatology, I also recommend Ruddiman's "Earth's Climate" as a good primer for jumping into climatology.

Comment: I second that. [EGU journals](http://www.egu.eu/publications/open-access-journals/) are also open-access, and [AGU](http://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/) and AAAS also  have a few open-access options ([Science Advances](http://advances.sciencemag.org/))